# Как в Ларавель создать отношение "ко многим через" через таблицу pivot?

Tags: php, laravel

У меня есть таблица categories с полями:
id
name

У меня есть таблица articles с полями:
id
title

Они связаны между собой как "многие ко многим" через таблицу pivot. В таблице pivot есть поля:
id
category_id
article_id

Кроме того, вторая таблица articles связана с таблицей comments как "один ко многим". Таблица comment имеет поля:
id
comments
Мне надо связать как-то таблицу categories с таблицей comments через таблицу pivot.
Я делаю так, но он не может найти какие-то поля. Понимаю, что надо передать в качестве параметров ключи таблиц, но в каком порядке? Или, может, я что-то не то делаю.

```
    public function cars()
    {
return $this->hasManyThrough(Comment::class, ArticleCategory::class, 'category_id', 'article_category_id', 'id', 'id');
    }
```

Comment: Пишите одно, пробуете другое. Что надо? Получить все комментарии (Comment) статьи (Article)?

Comment: Надо при выборе категории получить все комментарии, которые принадлежат статьям, относящимся к выбранной категории.